# Choice of finite element spaces in plasticity

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

I am planning to run numerical simulations in metal elastoplasticity (von-Mises yield condition with and without isotropic hardening). However, I am completely new to this subject and I am unsure about the choice of appropriate finite element spaces.

I read that a problem called “volumetric locking” may occur, which is related to the fact that standard finite element functions are not flexible enough to deal with the incompressible plastic deformations and that mixed formulations may be necessary.

I found some 2D simulations on the internet where it is pointed out that in this case quadratic triangles for the displacement field in a non-mixed formulation are sufficient. However, I am mainly interested in AXISYMMETRIC situations (also in the general 3D case) and I wasn’t able to find precise information on this topic in the literature.